# Ant failed to build on Ubuntu

Tags: android, ant, build

I hope someone can help me out with this problem. I am using an Ant Build to compile my java code but I get the following errors:

```
Buildfile: <PATH>

BUILD FAILED
<PATH>build.xml:55: sdk.dir is missing. Make sure 
    to generate local.properties using 'android update project' or to inject it
    through the ANDROID_HOME environment variable.

Total time: 345 milliseconds
```

I am using eclipse.

Answer (score 6):

There are two solutions to this problem, as described in the error message:

1. Set the value of the `sdk.dir` variable in the `local.properties` file in the root directory of your Android project. This needs to point to the location of your Android SDK installation. For example, I have the following line in mine:

   sdk.dir=/usr/local/bin/android-sdk-linux

   You can do this manually or use the `android update project` command to generate it for you.
2. Alternatively, you can set the `ANDROID_HOME` environment variable in your `.bashrc` file in your home directory. You can do this by adding something like the following line:

   export ANDROID_HOME=/usr/local/bin/android-sdk-linux

   Note that you will need to source your .bashrc file or close your console window and reopen it.

Comment: I can't find the command `android` anywhere. I've tried `locate android`. Seems like a simple mistake, but it's bugging me. On Ubuntu.

Comment: @Jason Have you installed the Android SDK? If so, `android` is located in the `tools` subdirectory where you installed it. On my development machine, I set `ANDROID_HOME` as explained in my answer here and I add `$ANDROID_HOME/tools` and `$ANDROID_HOME/platform_tools` to `PATH`.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice is it platform_tools or platform-tools?

Answer (score 0):

Can't tell without seeing your build.xml file. However, the message looks very detailed. It says you need to generate a "local.properties" file, probably to set where *sdk.dir* is located.

In Ant, you can have a properties file that sets properties your Ant `build.xml` file uses. It says you can use `android update project` to create this file. Again, it's hard to say without knowing what your `build.xml` looks like, what project you're trying to build, etc.

A quick Google pointed me to [this page](http://developer.android.com/tools/projects/projects-cmdline.html#UpdatingAProject).