# Installing cordova and adding a platform

Tags: android, cordova

I installed `Phonegap` in `Ubuntu 14.04` by using these commands:

```
$ sudo npm install -g phonegap
```

Then I installed cordova by using these commands:

```
$ sudo npm install -g cordova
```

Output was:

```
npm WARN engine npm@1.3.4: wanted: {"node":">=0.6","npm":"1"} (current: {"node":"0.10.33","npm":"2.1.5"})
/usr/bin/cordova -> /usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/bin/cordova
cordova@4.0.0 /usr/lib/node_modules/cordova
├── q@0.9.7
├── underscore@1.4.4
├── nopt@2.2.1 (abbrev@1.0.5)
└── cordova-lib@4.0.0 (osenv@0.0.3, properties-parser@0.2.3, bplist-parser@0.0.5, mime@1.2.11, semver@2.0.11, unorm@1.3.3, shelljs@0.3.0, dep-graph@1.1.0, elementtree@0.1.5, xcode@0.6.7, glob@3.2.11, npmconf@0.1.16, rc@0.3.0, plist@1.0.1, tar@0.1.20, npm@1.3.4, request@2.22.0, d8@0.4.4, cordova-js@3.7.Tne1)
```

I created a simple project by using this command:

```
$ cordova create hello com.example.hello HelloWorld
```

Output was:

```
Creating a new cordova project with name "HelloWorld" and id "com.ajay.hello" at location "/home/ajay/hello"
Downloading cordova library for www...
Download complete
```

Then I created path into the project by using `$ cd hello`.
Then I added android platform:

```
$ cordova platform add android
```

And this is the error:

```
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android/3.6.4
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android/3.6.4
npm http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android/-/cordova-android-3.6.4.tgz
npm http 200 https://registry.npmjs.org/cordova-android/-/cordova-android-3.6.4.tgz
Creating android project...

/home/ajay/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.4/package/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:126
                    throw e;
                          ^
Error: ANDROID_HOME is not set and "android" command not in your PATH. You must fulfill at least one of these conditions.
    at /home/ajay/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.4/package/bin/lib/check_reqs.js:159:19
    at _fulfilled (/home/ajay/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.4/package/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:798:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/home/ajay/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.4/package/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:827:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/home/ajay/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.4/package/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:760:13)
    at /home/ajay/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.4/package/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:821:14
    at flush (/home/ajay/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.4/package/bin/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:419:13)
    at Function.Module.runMain (module.js:499:11)
    at startup (node.js:119:16)
    at node.js:906:3
Error: /home/ajay/.cordova/lib/npm_cache/cordova-android/3.6.4/package/bin/create: Command failed with exit code 8
    at ChildProcess.whenDone (/usr/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/cordova-lib/src/cordova/superspawn.js:135:23)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (child_process.js:823:5)
```

How can I set ANDROID_HOME? Any leads?

Answer (score 2):

You can setup the ANDROID_HOME in you `.bashrc` by adding these:

```
ANDROID_HOME=/home/user/android-sdk-linux
export ANDROID_HOME=$ANDROID_HOME
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-7-oracle/

PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/build-tools
```

Probably you would have to change some values to match your configuration.

You will need to source your `.bashrc` file or close your terminal window and reopen it.

see also : [Ant failed to build on Ubuntu](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13837930/ant-failed-to-build-on-ubuntu)

Comment: What about if you're using a Mac? I get the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the path of your Android SDK, Android SDK Tools & Android SDK Platform-tools.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26216081/android-home-is-not-set-and-android-command-not-in-your-path-phonegap) will solve your problem.

Answer (score -1):

I just run `sudo uninstall cordova` then `sudo install cordova` then `cordova platform add android` , I am on Mac OSX Yosemite 10.10.3

I hope this helps :)